# Visual studio code can't complete variable names

Tags: c++, variables, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I tried several Auto completion tools, for example Intellisense in my visual studio code. But it can't completes variable names. How can I fix this?

[image: You can see screen]

Comment: Do you have the [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension installed? I think you need to enable auto-complete through some configuration, as it's experimental. Alternatively, use a full-blown IDE like Visual Studio.

Comment: It *does* propose known names starting with "sampl", doesn't it? It might take more than half a second for it to update its database and realize that you added a new name on the previous line.